# Lemma on partitioning columns of TU matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I'm currently looking at Lemma 5 in [András Mészáros](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=fwGnb_YAAAAJ)'s [A note on disjoint dijoins](https://web.cs.elte.hu/egres/qp/egresqp-15-05.pdf) [PDF].

**Lemma:** For a Totally Unimodular (TU) matrix $A$ and positive $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, if the sum of columns of $A$ have entries which are all divisible by $k$, then there is a partition of the columns into $k$ classes such that the sum of the columns in each class is the same.

Supposedly, this is taken from Alexander Schrijver's [Theory of Linear and Integer Programming](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Theory+of+Linear+and+Integer+Programming-p-9780471982326), but I cannot find it. Does anyone have insight on the proof of this lemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was based on Lemma 19.4 in the textbook, where we instead have that $Ay = 1$. Since $x_i \geq 0$ and $y = x_1 + \dots + x_k$, the $x_i$ represent a partition.